Can Mozart's Church Sonatas be performed with harpsichord instead of organ?
Can Mozart's Church Sonatas be performed with harpsichord instead of organ?
I don't think there is anything else to add to my question.
Of course I understand there is no reason this change couldn't technically be done. I'm just wondering if there is some reason it wouldn't work aesthetically. To me, the organ part looks like a continuo keyboard part and should work on harpsichord. Maybe some octave transpositions would be needed depending on keyboard ranges. I don't see any long pedals, only a few foot pedal indications, that might cause a problem. Otherwise I think those could be performed as trills or tremolos.

It unclear to me if you're asking a technical question about performing them on harpsichord vs. organ (you seem to say not), or if you're looking for opinions on whether it would sound good or not.

I'm interested in the sound good side. And whether the organ part does seem like a continuo part, as compared to something like a Bach choral prelude for organ, which clearly isn't like continuo. I think so. Just want to hear if someone disagrees, if I'm overlooking something.

I would think an important question would be "what would have been common and expected in Mozart's time." I'm not sure, but I do know that just because sonatas de chiesa are "in church" is no reason they can't use harpsichord.

I see a number of solo-keyboard transcriptions/arrangements on IMSLP, so clearly some people have thought it would work...

Can? Yes, of course. Arrangements are and always have been a common thing. Would it work out? Probably yes, with some adaptation maybe. Note that this is mostly functional music. The instrumentation is like this not because of the special sound of the organ, but it was music written for liturgical use, and in the church you just happen to have an organ. You could say this is music Mozart wrote for the sake of money, and is written for whatever is available. This also means that the music works well in different ensembles without lots of trouble.
But then it depends on the room. An organ tends to be louder than a Harpsichord, while the Harpsichord offers projection by overtones. The organ has a sustained sound, the harpsichord doesn’t. This means that in a church with a lot of reverb the outcome might be a lot different to say playing this in a small concert hall.

Here's the opening of one of the more lightly-scored ones, just organ, two violins and loosely-specified bass instruments.  The sustained A in bars 5-7 would be largely lost on harpsichord (though the instrument does have SOME sustain), and I'm not that keen on replacing it with a trill - though sure, try it out if you like!  I'm sure there are other similar moments.  But  in the absence of an organ, I don't think using harpsichord would sabotage the music too much.


Yeah, I was about to comment—"Otherwise I think those could be performed as trills or tremolos"—I'm not a continuo player, but that sounds "eww" to me. The sustain is provided by the other bass continuo instrument, and filling out the rest of the chord could be done if desired in an ad lib way other than trills or tremolos—a few chordal or arpeggiated quarter notes maybe, to match the melody.

@AndyBonner, I know what you mean about the trills. Personally, I don't like that on harpsichord, piano can do them softer. But I was thinking of long pedal trills like in Bach's D minor invention.

In a case like these three tied A's, couldn't those three notes be played without ties? That would just fit the meter and the rest of the rhythm.

@MichaelCurtis I'm pretty sure we're not even looking at Mozart's notes in that right hand. From https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mozart/jUcL1kBBmAkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=mozart+church+harpsichord&pg=PP77&printsec=frontcover: "The earliest are scored for two violins, bass, and organ continuo, but a few have notated organ parts, perhaps for when Mozart himself was not playing. The same music could easily have appeared in a divertimento with harpsichord continuo, but in the very last sonata Mozart treats the organ as a soloist."

@MichaelCurtis If we're going to work with what Mozart wrote instead of what someone else fleshed out, the "continuo" vs "notated" that Rushton refers to there means that, save for "a few" sonatas, Mozart just wrote a single-note bass line with figured bass.

@AndyBonner, that reference is fantastic! Not only does it confirm the continuo idea, but it brings in the galant/Rococo connection. Thanks!

@AndyBonner furthermore, even the editor who wrote the right hand part here (or Mozart, if it is his) would surely have written a different realization for the harpsichord (or fortepiano?) (with arpeggiation, for example), and I daresay that Mozart would not have hesitated to perform the piece without hesitation on whatever keyboard instrument was available, using whatever idiomatic figuration he found appropriate.
